# Ubuntu launcher auto-hide function on vmware fusion VM

Tags: 14.04, vmware-fusion

I just created a new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM in VMWare Fusion 8.5 running on MacOS Sierra host. Everything is running smooth but seems nope to have the launcher auto-hide function working. When I enable it in Ubuntu pref pane, launcher disappears and it's not possible to call for it going full left with mouse on the screen. The above behaviour is the same either at full screen or at single window. It is like the pointer does not "find" anything to reveal (the launcher) at the left border of the screen. Thank you for anybody's help.

Comment: A VM glitch. You can use the Super key to reveal the launcher. Or simply not hide it.

Comment: Super key is a good option. Thank you. That's acceptable for now. It remains a non due behaviour, anyway. In fact on VMWare forum nobody replied to my question...

Comment: It's probably has something to do with how the virtualization software uses borders.